# can a lambda or other method be used as a default parameter in python

Tags: python, lambda

I would like to use a default parameter that is initialized when you call the function so its a different default parameter each time you call it. To illustrate what I'm asking say you want a time diff function that defaults to the current time if 2nd time is not supplied:

normally you do something like this.

```
def tdiff(target_time, curr_time=None):
   if curr_time == None:
      curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
   return  curr_time - target_time
```

but it would be nicer to get rid of the if statement. Can this be done with lambda ? (Something like this)

```
def tdiff(target_time,  curr_time= lambda : datetime.now() ): 
    return curr_time - target_time
```

Edit:  I understand lambda will not work.  Will any other method work?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself, did it work? Please show some effort

Comment: @ResetACK  It actually didnt work as presented and i did not know if it was possible at all. So i thought it may work if you supply it some other way. For example supplying a tuple to a function like datetime((1,1,1)) would not work unless you unpack it like datetime(*(1,1,1))

Comment: No idea why this question received a down vote. It's a valid question and this feature would be really useful. Go try yourself is not good advise at all. Obviously OP has tried lmbda and it didn't work. But maybe others have other ideas that may work.

Answer (score 7):

> Can this be done with lambda ?

No. What you have is syntactically valid, but the default value of `curr_time` ends up being the lambda function, not the `datetime` value it would return if it were called. This can be worked around as:

```
if callable(curr_time):
    curr_time = curr_time()
```

but at that point, you might as well just use the `if curr_time is None:` approach you included in your question.

(Note that the comparison should be made as `is None`, not `== None`.)

Comment: Thank you @duskwuff. with 2 down votes its unlikely to get any attention now.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, for a pretty fundamental reason:

```
def f(arg=expression):
```

evaluates `expression` at the time the `def` statement is executed, and the object `expression` evaluates to is saved in the function object as the default value of local name `arg`.  When the function body is executed, within the body `arg` will simply retrieve the object `expression` originally evaluated to.  And nothing about any of that can be changed.

So, sure, you can supply a `lambda` expression, but then `arg` will be bound *to* the function object the `lambda` expression returns.  If you want to *call* that function object, you'll need to spell that as `arg()` in the body.  Plain old `arg` will merely retrieve the function object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers and to clarify I'm interested in any method not just lambda. So i looked at properties to see if that could work...

I created this to try it out.

```
import datetime

class DefaultParams():
    @property
    def curr_time( self ):
        return datetime.datetime.now()
```

when you access the property `defaults.curr_time` run it it yields the current time without being callable

```
>>> defaults = DefaultParams()
>>> defaults.curr_time
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 2, 10, 49, 16, 38295)
>>> defaults.curr_time
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 2, 10, 49, 17, 211985)
```

So i pluged that in and printed out the curr_time when you call tdiff

```
def tdiff(target_time,  curr_time= defaults.curr_time ): 
    print(curr_time)
    return curr_time - target_time
```

But when i run that it shows the curr_time reaming static @ 10:48:58.675151.

```
>>> tdiff(datetime.datetime.now())
2018-06-02 10:48:58.675151
datetime.timedelta(-1, 85430, 433255)
>>> tdiff(datetime.datetime.now())
2018-06-02 10:48:58.675151
datetime.timedelta(-1, 85429, 58707)
```

So it may not be possible in any way. I still think it would be useful for python to be able to do this kind of thing.